# fix Intellij dependancies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jersey, dependencies

I have an application that tests a REST api using TestNG as a driver.

We use Gradle as a build tool.

When I run the test from the command line, the code compiles and runs just fine.

When I try to run the code in Intellij (because, I occasionally like debugging code) I get the follow error:

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;

I know the problem is that for some reason IntelliJ has decided I need 1.17.1 of Jersey instead of 2.11.

When I look at the project structure, there is no indication of 1.17.1 as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sounds like a dependency of a dependency. If you find which other car 1.17.1 comes from, you can exclude it somehow via gradle? In maven there is the `<excludes>` tag, for example.

Comment: To add to what @vinkingsteve says, take a look at the [Dependency Management](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) chapter of the Gradle Documentation, paying particular attention to `Manage transitive dependencies` and `Excluding transitive dependencies` sections.